# NodeJS/Mongoose: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "..." at path "_id"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

On the main page, there is a hyperlink with `profile/5aa3cfb783622a145a86d616` that points to the profile page of a user, where `5aa3cfb783622a145a86d616` is the Object ID of the user (it is shown as `"_id" : ObjectId("5aa3cfb783622a145a86d616")` in MongoDB).

When I click on the link, the page fully loads without any problem. However, the terminal still says `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "..." at path "_id" for model "User"`, and the browser's favicon still shows that it is loading, even though the page has fully loaded.

I tried searching for answers, but none of them are specific to my problem.

---

**EDIT**

After playing with the code, I found that the problem seems to lie in the multiple "populate" methods, which I have previously ignored when simplifying the questions, as I thought there was no issue with it. I now include the full code below.

Inside the User document, there is a Post array containing the Post's ID. Each post document has Author, Likes, and Comment. In the Comment array, each comment document has the Author's ID. All of these have to be populated.

**NodeJS/Mongoose:**

```
router.get("/:id", function(req, res){
    User.findById(req.params.id).populate({
        path: 'posts',
        populate: [{
            path: 'author',
        },
        {
            path: 'likes',
        },
        {
            path: 'comments',
            populate: [{
                path: 'author'
            }]
        }]
    })
    .exec(function(err, user){
            console.log(user);
            res.render("profile", {user: user}); 
    });
});
```

**User Schema**

```
var UserSchema  = new mongoose.Schema({
    posts: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Post"
        }
    ]
});
```

**Post Schema**

```
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    },
    likes: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        }
    ],
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }
    ]
});
```

**Comment Schema**

```
var commentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }
});
```

When I `console.log(user)`, the terminal returns the following. I'm not too sure why it shows `author[object]` instead of its actual ID, maybe this is the problem?

```
{ posts: 
   [ { likes: [],
       comments: [],
       _id: 5aa3d0d806711d1483ae7e3e,
       __v: 0,
       author: [Object] },
     { likes: [],
       comments: [],
       _id: 5aa3cfc483622a145a86d618,
       __v: 0,
       author: [Object] },
     { likes: [],
       comments: [],
       _id: 5aa3cfbe83622a145a86d617,
       __v: 0,
       author: [Object] } ],
  __v: 3}
```

---

**EDIT 2**

Weird enough, my other route which has the same structure (except its `friendPosts`) is working without any issue.

```
router.get("/home", function(req, res){
    User
        .findById(req.user._id)
        .populate({
            path: 'friendPosts',
            populate: [{
                path: 'author',
            },
            {
                path: 'likes',
            },
            {
                path: 'comments',
                populate: [{
                    path: 'author'
                }]
            }]
        })
    .exec(function(err, currentUser){
            res.render("main/home", {user: currentUser}); 
    });
});
```

Comment: console your req.params.id and see what it has...

Comment: try casting the `id` from a `string` to a `ObjectId` like : `User.findById(ObjectId.fromString( req.params.id), ... `

Comment: @AshishChoudhary It shows `5aa3cfb783622a145a86d616`.

Comment: @Taki The code editor says `ObjectId is not defined; please fix or add /* global ObjectId */`?

Comment: @steven try this `User.findOne({_id: req.params.id }, function (err, user) { ... })`

Comment: try `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.fromString(req.params.id)` @Steven

Comment: It seems I have missed out some important detail when simplifying the questions. I have edited the questions to include the details as well.

Comment: @steven you have populated the author field... that's why it returns `author object... path: 'posts',
        populate: [{
            path: 'author',
        }` ... Remove it then you will get actual ids

Comment: @AshishChoudhary I don't quite understand...Could you show me what to remove?

Comment: see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this:

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongoose').Types;

router.get("/:id", function(req, res) {

    const { id } = req.params;

    User.findOne({ id: ObjectId(id)}).populate({
      path: 'posts',
      populate: [{
                path: 'author',
            },
            {
                path: 'likes',
            },
            {
                path: 'comments',
                populate: [{
                    path: 'author'
                }]
            }
        ]
    }).exec(function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        res.render("profile");
    });

});
```

Comment: I think something missing while populate